# Compare if two dates are within same week in android

Tags: java, android, date

I have two dates.Got them from something like......

```
Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
year=c.get(c.YEAR);
month=c.get(c.MONTH);
month++;
date=c.get(c.DATE);
```

and other date is broken into date2,month2

**Now I want to see if both of them are in the same week.**

It's possible through lots of calculation and logic.Problem occurs when 1st date is suppose 03 March and 2nd date is 28Feb. Both of them are in same week but difficult to compare/check that. So I want to know if there is any built in function or any way to compare them easily.Please help..........

Comment: "In the same week" and "within a week" aren't necessarily the same thing. For example, "this Friday" is within a week of "next Monday", but they're not in the same week.

Comment: Agreed - you need to specify whether you want your function to determine whether the dates are within a week of each other (ie date1 - date2 < 7 days) or fall in the same week (Mon - Sun)(or Sun - Sat). The first problem is an easy check, the second follows SmartLemon's solution below.

Comment: I meant same week. That means if two dates are inside of last Sunday to next Saturday.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

use something like this:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
Integer year1 = c.get(c.YEAR);
Integer week1 = c.get(c.WEEK_OF_YEAR);

Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTimeInMillis(/*Second date in millis here*/);
Integer year2 = c.get(c.YEAR);
Integer week2 = c.get(c.WEEK_OF_YEAR);

if(year1 == year2) {
    if(week1 == week2) {
         //Do what you want here
    }
}
```

This should do it :D

Comment: if my date is 31-Dec(Tuesday) , then 1st-Jan (Wednesday) is not considered as same week by above logic.

Comment: Just letting you know is date is today, and you are checking for tomorrow it will work, because the weekofyear at the moment is actually 1

Comment: Use `getWeekYear()` instead of `get(c.YEAR)` to obtain the year that the week number belongs to even of the week crosses New Year. Should solve your problem, @harshal.

Answer (score 5):

You can get the week number for your date using `c.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR)` and compare the results for your two dates.

Also accessing constants via instance variables (`c.YEAR`) is not recommended - access them using classes (`Calendar.YEAR`).

Comment: But first you want to check if they are the same year, other wise you could be comparing two different years which could be slightly different

Answer (score 4):

Just posting a slightly modified solution based on @FabianCook and as pointed out by @harshal his solution doesn't cater for two dates on different years but in the same week.

The modification is to actually set the DAY_OF_WEEK in both Calendar dates to point to Monday.....in this case both dates will be set to the same day even if they are in different years and then we can compare them.

```
Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
cal1.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
int year1 = cal1.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int week1 = cal1.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);

Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
cal2.setTimeInMillis(/*Second date in millis here*/);
cal2.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
int year2 = cal2.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int week2 = cal2.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);

if(year1 == year2 && week1 == week2){
    //Do what you want here
}
```

Answer (score 4):

## Use *`java.time`*

You can get it available the following ways:

**Java 8+** and **Android API 26+**: directly available
**Java 6** and **7**: [ThreeTenBP](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/)
**Android 25** and lower: [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP)

[**It is not recommended to use `java.util.Calendar` and `java.util.Date` anymore.**](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)

## How to find out if two given dates are in the same calendar week?

**Using plain `java.time`:**

```
public boolean inSameCalendarWeek(LocalDate firstDate, LocalDate secondDate) {
    // get a reference to the system of calendar weeks in your defaul locale
    WeekFields weekFields = WeekFields.of(Locale.getDefault());
    // find out the calendar week for each of the dates
    int firstDatesCalendarWeek = firstDate.get(weekFields.weekOfWeekBasedYear());
    int secondDatesCalendarWeek = secondDate.get(weekFields.weekOfWeekBasedYear());
    /*
     * find out the week based year, too,
     * two dates might be both in a calendar week number 1 for example,
     * but in different years
     */
    int firstWeekBasedYear = firstDate.get(weekFields.weekBasedYear());
    int secondWeekBasedYear = secondDate.get(weekFields.weekBasedYear());
    // return if they are equal or not
    return firstDatesCalendarWeek == secondDatesCalendarWeek
            && firstWeekBasedYear == secondWeekBasedYear;
}
```

**You can do that with simple `int` values, too:**

```
public static boolean inSameCalendarWeek(int firstYear, int firstMonth, int firstDayOfMonth,
        int secondYear, int secondMonth, int secondDayOfMonth) {
    // create LocalDates using the integers provided
    LocalDate firstDate = LocalDate.of(firstYear, firstMonth, firstDayOfMonth);
    LocalDate secondDate = LocalDate.of(secondYear, secondMonth, secondDayOfMonth);
    // get a reference to the system of calendar weeks in your defaul locale
    WeekFields weekFields = WeekFields.of(Locale.getDefault());
    // find out the calendar week for each of the dates
    int firstDatesCalendarWeek = firstDate.get(weekFields.weekOfWeekBasedYear());
    int secondDatesCalendarWeek = secondDate.get(weekFields.weekOfWeekBasedYear());
    /*
     * find out the week based year, too,
     * two dates might be both in a calendar week number 1 for example,
     * but in different years
     */
    int firstWeekBasedYear = firstDate.get(weekFields.weekBasedYear());
    int secondWeekBasedYear = secondDate.get(weekFields.weekBasedYear());
    // return if they are equal or not
    return firstDatesCalendarWeek == secondDatesCalendarWeek
            && firstWeekBasedYear == secondWeekBasedYear;
}
```

**In case you have to extend or use legacy code:**

```
public static boolean inSameCalendarWeek(Calendar firstCalendar, Calendar secondCalendar) {
    // create LocalDates from Instants created from the given Calendars
    LocalDate firstDate = LocalDate.from(firstCalendar.toInstant());
    LocalDate secondDate = LocalDate.from(secondCalendar.toInstant());
    // get a reference to the system of calendar weeks in your defaul locale
    WeekFields weekFields = WeekFields.of(Locale.getDefault());
    // find out the calendar week for each of the dates
    int firstDatesCalendarWeek = firstDate.get(weekFields.weekOfWeekBasedYear());
    int secondDatesCalendarWeek = secondDate.get(weekFields.weekOfWeekBasedYear());
    /*
     * find out the week based year, too,
     * two dates might be both in a calendar week number 1 for example,
     * but in different years
     */
    int firstWeekBasedYear = firstDate.get(weekFields.weekBasedYear());
    int secondWeekBasedYear = secondDate.get(weekFields.weekBasedYear());
    // return if they are equal or not
    return firstDatesCalendarWeek == secondDatesCalendarWeek
            && firstWeekBasedYear == secondWeekBasedYear;
}
```

The output of the following code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // a date from calendar week 1 in the week based year 2020
    LocalDate janFirst2020 = LocalDate.of(2020, 1, 1);
    // another date from calendar week 1 in the week based year 2020 
    LocalDate decThirtyFirst2019 = LocalDate.of(2019, 12, 31);
    System.out.println(inSameCalendarWeek(janFirst2020, decThirtyFirst2019));

    // then a third date from calendar week 1, but this time in the week based year 2021
    LocalDate janSeventh2021 = LocalDate.of(2021, 1, 7);
    System.out.println(inSameCalendarWeek(janSeventh2021, decThirtyFirst2019));
}
```

is therefore

```
true
false
```

in my locale.

Comment: @OleV.V. very good point, thanks... Added the check and an example where this would have lead to a false positive otherwise.

Comment: @deHaar `It is not recommended to use java.util.Calendar and java.util.Date anymore.`  - why exactly?

Comment: @Anatolii have a look at [this Technical Article by Oracle](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html), it even starts with the question *Why do we need a new date and time library?*...

Comment: @deHaar thanks for your answer! I would suggest to put think link next to the sentence about `Calendar` and `Date`.

Comment: @Anatolii very good suggestion, thanks... I made that sentence itself point to the article.

Answer (score 1):

It's a java solution. Following code segment checks if two dates are within same week. **It also covers edge cases, where week starts in one calendar year (December) and ends in next year (January).**

**Note:** Code has a dependency on joda-time:

```
compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.3'


public static boolean isSameWeek(final Date d1, final Date d2) {
    if ((d1 == null) || (d2 == null))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The date must not be null");

    return isSameWeek(new DateTime(d1), new DateTime(d2));
}

public static boolean isSameWeek(final DateTime d1, final DateTime d2) {
    if ((d1 == null) || (d2 == null))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The date must not be null");

    // It is important to use week of week year & week year

    final int week1 = d1.getWeekOfWeekyear();
    final int week2 = d2.getWeekOfWeekyear();

    final int year1 = d1.getWeekyear();
    final int year2 = d2.getWeekyear();

    final int era1 = d1.getEra();
    final int era2 = d2.getEra();

    // Return true if week, year and era matches
    if ((week1 == week2) && (year1 == year2) && (era1 == era2))
        return true;

    // Return false if none of the conditions are satisfied
    return false;
}
```

Test case:

```
public class TestDateUtil {

@Test
public void testIsSameWeek() {

    final DateTime d1 = new DateTime(2014, 12, 31, 0, 0);
    final DateTime d2 = new DateTime(2015, 1, 1, 0, 0);
    final DateTime d3 = new DateTime(2015, 1, 2, 0, 0);
    final DateTime d4 = new DateTime(2015, 1, 8, 0, 0);

    assertTrue(isSameWeek(d1, d2));
    assertTrue(isSameWeek(d2, d1));

    assertTrue(isSameWeek(d2, d3));
    assertTrue(isSameWeek(d3, d2));

    assertFalse(isSameWeek(d2, d4));
    assertFalse(isSameWeek(d4, d2));

    assertFalse(isSameWeek(d1, d4));
    assertFalse(isSameWeek(d4, d1));

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using

```
date1.with(previousOrSame(MONDAY)).equals(date2.with(previousOrSame(MONDAY)))
```

assuming that weeks start on Monday.

Answer (score 0):

```
private int weeksBetween(Calendar startDate, Calendar endDate) {
    startDate.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    startDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    startDate.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    int start = (int)TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(
        startDate.getTimeInMillis())
        - startDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    int end = (int)TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(
        endDate.getTimeInMillis());
    return (end - start) / 7;
}
```

if this method returns 0 they are in the same week

if this method return 1 endDate is the week after startDate

if this method returns -1 endDate is the week before startDate

you get the idea

Answer (score 0):

Let's say, a week starts one year and ends the next year and we pick 2 dates from this week so that they are in different years. Then, the accepted answer yields the wrong result as it checks that the dates are in the **SAME YEAR!**.

To improve the solution, one could obtain a date corresponding to some day (it could be `Monday`) of its week and then check that both dates belong to the same day. However, before doing so make sure that both Calendar objects are in the **SAME** time zone. So, set the time zone of one to another. Also, the solution below works for every **API** level as it doesn't require the usage of `getWeekOfWeekyear()` or `getWeekYear()` (these work with **API** `24` and higher.

```
public boolean isSameWeek(Calendar calendar1, Calendar calendar2) {
    Calendar calendar2Copy = (Calendar) calendar2.clone();
    calendar2Copy.setTimeZone(calendar1.getTimeZone());
    calendar1.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
    calendar2Copy.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);

    return calendar1.get(Calendar.YEAR) == calendar2Copy.get(Calendar.YEAR)
            && calendar1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) == calendar2Copy.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this will give true if two dates from same week

```
fun isEqualWeek(date1: Long, date2: Long):Boolean{
    val cal1 = Calendar.getInstance()
    val cal2 = Calendar.getInstance()
    cal1.time = Date(date1)
    cal2.time = Date(date2)
    return (cal1.get(Calendar.YEAR) == cal2.get(Calendar.YEAR)) && (cal1.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR) == cal2.get(
        Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR
    ))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here in Joda's Library I found that the week starts from Monday, but I wanted the week to start from Sunday, so just used the below function :

```
  public static boolean isSameWeek(final Date initDate, final Date finalDate) {
    if (initDate != null && finalDate != null) {
        Calendar initCalender = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar finalCalender = Calendar.getInstance();
        initCalender.setTime(initDate);
        finalCalender.setTime(finalDate);
        if (finalCalender.get(Calendar.YEAR) >= initCalender.get(Calendar.YEAR)) {
            //check for same year
            if (finalCalender.get(Calendar.YEAR) == initCalender.get(Calendar.YEAR)) {
                if (finalCalender.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR) == initCalender.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR)) {
                    return true;
                }
            } else //check whether next corresponding year
                if (finalCalender.get(Calendar.YEAR) - initCalender.get(Calendar.YEAR) == 1) {
                    if (initCalender.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR) == 1 || initCalender.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR) == 53) {
                        if (finalCalender.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR) == 1) {
                            if (initCalender.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SATURDAY && finalCalender.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SUNDAY) {
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Final Date should be greater or equal to Initial Date");
        }
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The date must not be null");
    }
    return false;
}
```