# Get the number of weeks between two Dates.

Tags: java, date, jodatime

Im working in a project and I got two types in Date. I want to calculate the number of weeks between these two dates. The dates can be in diffrent years. Is there any good solution for this?

I have tried to implemenent this with Joda-time which was suggested in other topics..

Im not familar with this library, but I tried to do something like this:

```
public static int getNumberOfWeeks(Date f, Date l){
    Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    c1.setTime(f);
    c2.setTime(l);
    DateTime start = new DateTime(c1.YEAR, c1.MONTH, c1.DAY_OF_MONTH, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    DateTime end   = new DateTime(c2.YEAR, c2.MONTH, c2.DAY_OF_MONTH, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    Interval interval = new Interval(start, end);
    Period p = interval.toPeriod();
    return p.getWeeks();
}
```

But this is completely wrong... any suggestions ?

Comment: FYI: The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode). Its creator, [Stephen Colebourne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38896/jodastephen), went on to lead [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310) defining the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8+. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It is pretty easy with [joda time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/):

```
DateTime dateTime1 = new DateTime(date1);
DateTime dateTime2 = new DateTime(date2);

int weeks = Weeks.weeksBetween(dateTime1, dateTime2).getWeeks();
```

Comment: Correct answer, but becoming outdated. The creators of [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) have said we should migrate to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework.

Comment: True in this case, but not an option, if you rely on the [Interval](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html) class for example. There is no alternative for that in java.time.

Comment: You will find an [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html) class in the [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project that extends java.time. ThreeTen-Extra also serves as a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time classes. But true that Joda-Time and java.time are not at 100% feature parity. While largely equivalent, each has a few features the other lacks.

Comment: About Threeten-Extra, it seems to be almost dormant (see low activity, not even a replacement for Jodas PeriodFormatter exists yet). Another alternative having interval support etc. can be found in my lib Time4J which is interoperable with java.time-package and can be used as extension, too.

Answer (score 45):

Updating answer to account for Java 8

```
// TechTrip - ASSUMPTION d1 is earlier than d2
// leave that for exercise
public static long getFullWeeks(Calendar d1, Calendar d2){

    Instant d1i = Instant.ofEpochMilli(d1.getTimeInMillis());
    Instant d2i = Instant.ofEpochMilli(d2.getTimeInMillis());

    LocalDateTime startDate = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(d1i, ZoneId.systemDefault());
    LocalDateTime endDate = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(d2i, ZoneId.systemDefault());

    return ChronoUnit.WEEKS.between(startDate, endDate);
}
```

Comment: Note that the start date is always inclusive while the end date is exclusive.

Comment: here if i am giving 28 Feb 2018 and 2 march 2019, it is calculating 1 week, it should calculate 2 weeks. do you help to me calculate ?

Comment: @IrfanNasim exactly what I am looking for.did you find any solution?

Comment: `LocalDateTime` cannot represents a moment, a specific point on the timeline. So it’s use here is not appropriate. Replace with `ZonedDateTime` to make a better example.

Answer (score 13):

## tl;dr

```
ChronoUnit
.WEEKS
.between(
    myJavaUtilDate_Start.toInstant().atZone( ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ) , 
    myJavaUtilDate_Stop.toInstant().atZone( ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ) 
)
```

> 7

## java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These new classes supplant the old date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java.

The *java.time* classes also supplant the highly successful [Joda-Time](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/) framework. Both *java.time* and *Joda-Time* are led by [Stephen Colbourne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38896/jodastephen).

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

### `Instant` replaces `java.util.Date`

The modern class `Instant` replaces the legacy class `java.util.Date`. Both represent a moment in UTC, a specific point on the timeline. Both internally use a count since the same epoch reference of the first moment of 1970 in UTC, 1970-01-01T00:00Z. The old class uses a count of milliseconds, while `Instant` uses a finer count of nanoseconds.

To convert, call new methods added to the old classes.

```
Instant start = myJavaUtilDateStart.toInstant() ;
Instant stop = myJavaUtilDateStop.toInstant() ;
```

Let's make this concrete with some example values.

```
Instant start = OffsetDateTime.of( 2020 , 1 , 23 , 15 , 30 , 0 , 0 , ZoneOffset.UTC ).toInstant();
Instant stop = OffsetDateTime.of( 2020 , 1 , 23 , 15 , 30 , 0 , 0 , ZoneOffset.UTC ).plusWeeks(7 ).toInstant();
```

### Moments versus dates

Both of our `Instant` objects represent a moment. The goal is a count of weeks. Weeks means days, and days mean certain dates on the calendar.

So we have a bit of a mismatch. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by time zone. A few minutes after midnight in Paris France is a new date. Meanwhile in Montréal Québec, being several hours behind, that same moment is still “yesterday”, the date before on the calendar. So we cannot directly calculate weeks from a pair of moments.

You must first decide on the time zone by which you want to perceive a calendar for those moments.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
```

### `ZonedDateTime`

Apply this `ZoneId` to our `Instant` objects to adjust into a time zone, yielding a pair of [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) objects.

```
ZonedDateTime startZdt = start.atZone( z ) ;
ZonedDateTime stopZdt = stop.atZone( z ) ;
```

### `ChronoUnit.WEEKS`

Now we can use the `ChronoUnit` enum to calculate elapsed weeks.

long weeks = ChronoUnit.WEEKS.between( startZdt , stopZdt );

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "start.toString() = " + start );
System.out.println( "stop.toString() = " + stop );
System.out.println( "startZdt.toString() = " + startZdt );
System.out.println( "stopZdt.toString() = " + stopZdt );
System.out.println( "weeksCount: " + weeksCount );
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/UphAm6).

> start.toString() = 2020-01-23T15:30:00Z
>
> stop.toString() = 2020-03-12T15:30:00Z
>
> startZdt.toString() = 2020-01-23T10:30-05:00[America/Montreal]
>
> stopZdt.toString() = 2020-03-12T11:30-04:00[America/Montreal]
>
> weeksCount: 7

## ThreeTen-Extra

The [ThreeTen-Extra](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project adds functionality to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later.

### `Weeks` class

That project includes a [`Weeks`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/Weeks.html) class to represent a number of weeks. Not only can it calculate, it is also meant to be used in your code as a type-safe object. Such use also helps to make your code self-documenting.

You can instantiate by providing a pair of points in time with the [`Weeks.between`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Weeks.html#between-java.time.temporal.Temporal-java.time.temporal.Temporal-) method. Those points in time can be anything implementing [java.time.temporal.Temporal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/Temporal.html) including [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/YearMonth.html), [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/YearMonth.html), [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/YearMonth.html), [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/YearMonth.html), `Year`, [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/YearMonth.html), and more.

Your [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html) objects can be easily converted to `Instant` objects, moments on the timeline in UTC with a resolution in nanoseconds. Look at new methods added to the old date-time classes. For going from Date to Instant, call [`java.util.Date::toInstant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toInstant--).

```
Weeks weeks = Weeks.between( startZdt , stopZdt );
```

You can ask for the number of weeks.

```
int weeksNumber = weeks.getAmount(); // The number of weeks in this Weeks object.
```

You can also do much more.

Generate a string in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. The `P` marks the beginning. The `W` indicates a number of weeks.

> PW7

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

[image: Table of which java.time library to use with which version of Java or Android]

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Normally I don't like to downvote, but do here for following reasons: a) your code throws an `UnsupportedTemporalTypeException`. b) Introducing Threeten-Extra as solution is silly because Java-8 already supports the calculation of elapsed weeks, see the correct answer of @TechTrip here, so what is the point to add an extra dependency only for that purpose? c) Threeten-Extra has no "official" status. Future enhancements going into `java.time` happen directly on OpenJDK (see all the scheduled features for Java-9 in java.time-component).

Comment: @MenoHochschild Thanks for the criticisms. With those in mind, I revamped my Answer.

Comment: OK, I have undone the downvote after your corrections.

Answer (score 8):

Using the date arithmetic in `java.util.Calendar`:

```
public static int getWeeksBetween (Date a, Date b) {

    if (b.before(a)) {
        return -getWeeksBetween(b, a);
    }
    a = resetTime(a);
    b = resetTime(b);

    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    cal.setTime(a);
    int weeks = 0;
    while (cal.getTime().before(b)) {
        // add another week
        cal.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 1);
        weeks++;
    }
    return weeks;
}

public static Date resetTime (Date d) {
    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    cal.setTime(d);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    return cal.getTime();
}
```

Comment: Will this function work if the dates are in different years?

Comment: You need to align the dates to the first day of week, otherwise it will return 1 for different days in the same week

Comment: Something like         cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, cal.getFirstDayOfWeek());

Answer (score 8):

If your requirement is like the start date is 03-Apr-2020 and end date is 07-Apr-2020. the difference between the two dates is 4 days. Now the **number of weeks between two dates as 1** for this you can use below snippet.

```
ChronoUnit.WEEKS.between(LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate);
```

But If your requirement is like 03-Apr-2020 is in one week and 07-Apr-2020 is in another week so you want the **number of weeks between two dates as 2** you can use the below snippet.

```
LocalDate actualStartDate=...
LocalDate actualEndDate=...

LocalDate startDate = actualStartDate.with(TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY)) 

LocalDate endDate = actualEndDate.with(TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame(DayOfWeek.SATURDAY)) 

long daysBetweenTwoDates = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(startDate, endDate);
int numberOfWeeks =  (int)Math.ceil(daysBetweenTwoDates/7.0);
```

Tested in java 1.8

Comment: Tested in a proyect with JDK11 Base (correct)

Answer (score 2):

```
Calendar a = new GregorianCalendar(2002,1,22);
    Calendar b = new GregorianCalendar(2002,1,28);
    System.out.println(a.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR));
    System.out.println(b.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR)); 
   int weeks = b.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR)-a.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
    System.out.println(weeks);
```

try this must work

```
    Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar1.set(2007, 01, 10);
calendar2.set(2007, 07, 01);
long milliseconds1 = calendar1.getTimeInMillis();
long milliseconds2 = calendar2.getTimeInMillis();
long diff = milliseconds2 - milliseconds1;
int diffWeeks = (int)diff / (7*24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

Comment: This method does not properly work with dates in different years

Comment: question is already about how to count weeks in different years. solution does not make sense!

Answer (score 2):

Here are 2 methods I wrote that not based on an external library.
The first method is when **Monday** is the first day of the week.
The second method is when **Sunday** is the first day of the week.

Please read the comments inside the code, there is an option to return the number of the full weeks between 2 dates,
 and also with the fraction of the remaining days before and after the 2 dates.

```
public static int getNumberOfFullWeeks(LocalDate startDate,LocalDate endDate)
{
    int dayBeforeStartOfWeek = 0;
    int daysAfterLastFullWeek = 0;

    if(startDate.getDayOfWeek() != DayOfWeek.MONDAY)
    {
        // get the partial value before loop starting
        dayBeforeStartOfWeek = 7-startDate.getDayOfWeek().getValue() + 1;
    }

    if(endDate.getDayOfWeek() != DayOfWeek.SUNDAY)
    {
        // get the partial value after loop ending
        daysAfterLastFullWeek = endDate.getDayOfWeek().getValue();
    }

    LocalDate d1 = startDate.plusDays(dayBeforeStartOfWeek); // now it is the first day of week;
    LocalDate d2 = endDate.minusDays(daysAfterLastFullWeek); // now it end in the last full week

    // Count how many days there are of full weeks that start on Mon and end in Sun
    // if the startDate and endDate are less than a full week the while loop
    // will not iterate at all because d1 and d2 will be the same date
    LocalDate looper = d1;
    int counter = 1;
    while (looper.isBefore(d2))
    {
        counter++;
        looper = looper.plusDays(1);
    }

    // Counter / 7 will always be an integer that will represents full week
    // because we started to count at Mon and stop counting in Sun
    int fullWeeks = counter / 7;

    System.out.println("Full weeks between dates: "
            + fullWeeks + " Days before the first monday: "
            + dayBeforeStartOfWeek + " "
            + " Days after the last sunday: " + daysAfterLastFullWeek);
    System.out.println(startDate.toString() + " - " + endDate.toString());

    // You can also get a decimal value of the full weeks plus the fraction if the days before
    // and after the full weeks
    float full_weeks_decimal = (float)fullWeeks;
    float fraction = ((float)dayBeforeStartOfWeek + (float)daysAfterLastFullWeek) / 7.0F;
    System.out.println("Full weeks with fraction: " + String.valueOf(fraction + full_weeks_decimal));

    return fullWeeks;
}

public static int getNumberOfFullWeeks_WeekStartAtSunday(LocalDate startDate,LocalDate endDate)
{
    int dayBeforeStartOfWeek = 0;
    int daysAfterLastFullWeek = 0;

    if(startDate.getDayOfWeek() != DayOfWeek.SUNDAY)
    {
        // get the partial value before loop starting
        dayBeforeStartOfWeek = 7-getDayOfWeekBySundayIs0(startDate.getDayOfWeek()) + 1;
    }

    if(endDate.getDayOfWeek() != DayOfWeek.SATURDAY)
    {
        // get the partial value after loop ending
        daysAfterLastFullWeek = 1+getDayOfWeekBySundayIs0(endDate.getDayOfWeek());
    }

    LocalDate d1 = startDate.plusDays(dayBeforeStartOfWeek); // now it is the first day of week;
    LocalDate d2 = endDate.minusDays(daysAfterLastFullWeek); // now it end in the last full week

    // Count how many days there are of full weeks that start on Sun and end in Sat
    // if the startDate and endDate are less than a full week the while loop
    // will not iterate at all because d1 and d2 will be the same date
    LocalDate looper = d1;
    int counter = 1;
    while (looper.isBefore(d2))
    {
        counter++;
        looper = looper.plusDays(1);
    }

    // Counter / 7 will always be an integer that will represents full week
    // because we started to count at Sun and stop counting in Sat
    int fullWeeks = counter / 7;

    System.out.println("Full weeks between dates: "
            + fullWeeks + " Days before the first sunday: "
            + dayBeforeStartOfWeek + " "
            + " Days after the last saturday: " + daysAfterLastFullWeek);
    System.out.println(startDate.toString() + " - " + endDate.toString());

    // You can also get a decimal value of the full weeks plus the fraction if the days before
    // and after the full weeks
    float full_weeks_decimal = (float)fullWeeks;
    float fraction = ((float)dayBeforeStartOfWeek + (float)daysAfterLastFullWeek) / 7.0F;
    System.out.println("Full weeks with fraction: " + String.valueOf(fraction + full_weeks_decimal));

    return fullWeeks;
}

   public static int getDayOfWeekBySundayIs0(DayOfWeek day)
    {
        if(day == DayOfWeek.SUNDAY)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            // NOTE: getValue() is starting to count from 1 and not from 0
            return  day.getValue();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I agree that it’s good t use the built-in java.time ( `LocalDate` and `DayOfWeek`). Your solution appears unnecessarily complicated in my eyes. Thanks for sharing your code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want exact number of full weeks use below method, where end date is exclusive:

```
public static long weeksBetween(Date date1, Date date2) {
    return WEEKS.between(date1.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate(),
        date2.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate());
  }
```

If you want a ceil version of this, use below:

```
public static long weeksBetween(Date date1, Date date2) {
    long daysBetween = DAYS.between(date1.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate(),
        date2.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate()) + 1;
    return daysBetween / 7 + (daysBetween % 7 == 0 ? 0 : 1);
  }
```

Comment: Dear Downvoter, please be courteous to add a comment mentioning the reason for your downvote.

Answer (score 0):

You may do it the following way:

```
// method header not shown
// example dates:
f = new GregorianCalendar(2009,Calendar.AUGUST,1);
l = new GregorianCalendar(2010,Calendar.SEPTEMBER,1);
DateTime start = new DateTime(f);
DateTime end = new DateTime(l);
// Alternative to above - example dates with joda:
// DateTime start = new DateTime(2009,8,1,0,0,0,0);
// DateTime end = new DateTime(2010,9,1,0,0,0,0);
Interval interval = new Interval(start,end);
int weeksBetween = interval.toPeriod(PeriodType.weeks()).getWeeks();
// return weeksBetween;
```

This should give you an int representing the number of weeks between the two dates.

Comment: If you use nansen's answer you don't need the line with Interval in the above example. It is even better.

Answer (score 0):

Joda Time computes weeks with durations of two dates which may not meet our requirements in some cases. I have a method with Joda Time to compute natural weeks between two dates. Hope it can help you. If you don't use Joda Time, you may modify the code with Calendar to do the same thing.

```
//Unlike Joda Time Weeks.weeksBetween() that returns whole weeks computed
//from duration, we return natural weeks between two dates based on week of year
public static int weeksBetween(ReadablePartial date1, ReadablePartial date2) {
    int comp = date1.compareTo(date2);
    if (comp == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    if (comp > 0) {
        ReadablePartial mid = date2;
        date2 = date1;
        date1 = mid;
    }

    int year1 = date1.get(DateTimeFieldType.weekyear());
    int year2 = date2.get(DateTimeFieldType.weekyear());

    if (year1 == year2) {
        return date2.get(DateTimeFieldType.weekOfWeekyear()) - date1.get(DateTimeFieldType.weekOfWeekyear());
    }

    int weeks1 = 0;

    LocalDate lastDay1 = new LocalDate(date1.get(DateTimeFieldType.year()), 12, 31);
    if (lastDay1.getWeekyear() > year1) {
        lastDay1 = lastDay1.minusDays(7);
        weeks1++;
    }

    weeks1 += lastDay1.getWeekOfWeekyear() - date1.get(DateTimeFieldType.weekOfWeekyear());

    int midWeeks = 0;
    for (int i = year1 + 1; i < year2; i++) {
        LocalDate y1 = new LocalDate(i, 1, 1);
        int yearY1 = y1.getWeekyear();
        if (yearY1 < i) {
            y1 = y1.plusDays(7);
            midWeeks++;
        }

        LocalDate y2 = new LocalDate(i, 12, 31);
        int yearY2 = y2.getWeekyear();
        if (yearY2 > i) {
            y2 = y2.minusDays(7);
            midWeeks++;
        }

        midWeeks += y2.getWeekOfWeekyear() - y1.getWeekOfWeekyear();
    }

    int weeks2 = 0;
    LocalDate firstDay2 = new LocalDate(date2.get(DateTimeFieldType.year()), 1, 1);
    if (firstDay2.getWeekyear() < firstDay2.getYear()) {
        firstDay2 = firstDay2.plusDays(7);
        weeks2++;
    }
    weeks2 += date2.get(DateTimeFieldType.weekOfWeekyear()) - firstDay2.getWeekOfWeekyear();

    return weeks1 + midWeeks + weeks2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    int startWeek = c1.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
    int endWeek = c2.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);    

    int diff = c2.get(Calendar.YEAR) - c1.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    int deltaYears = 0;
    for(int i = 0;i < diff;i++){
        deltaYears += c1.getWeeksInWeekYear();
        c1.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);        
    }
    diff = (endWeek + deltaYears) - startWeek;
```

Includes the year differences.
This worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

```
private int weeksBetween(Calendar startDate, Calendar endDate) {
    startDate.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    startDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    startDate.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    int start = (int)TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(
        startDate.getTimeInMillis())
        - startDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    int end = (int)TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(
        endDate.getTimeInMillis());
    return (end - start) / 7;
}
```

if this method returns 0 they are in the same week

if this method return 1 endDate is the week after startDate

if this method returns -1 endDate is the week before startDate

you get the idea

Comment: Please do not post [duplicate answers](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/211726/206345). Instead, consider other actions that could help future users find the answer they need, as described in the linked post.

Comment: @Mogsdad this is not a duplicate answer this is an answer that does not require the use of joda-time(which people may not want to download for a simple function) and also this function works no matter what the dates are. The other stated answers only work if both answers are in the same year or ignore things like daylight savings

Comment: By "duplicate", I'm not saying you've repeated an answer that is on this question, rather that you've pasted your own [duplicate from a different question.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37307327/1677912) If the _questions_ are the same, they should be marked as duplicates. If not, your _answer_ should be tailored to address the specific question. Alternatively, a _comment_ linking to the other answer is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Without using JodaTime, I was able to accurately calculate the number of weeks between 2 calendars (which accounts for leap years etc.)

```
private fun calculateNumberOfWeeks() {
    val calendarFrom = Calendar.getInstance()
    calendarFrom.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
    calendarFrom.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0)
    calendarFrom.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)
    calendarFrom.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0)

    val calendarTo = Calendar.getInstance()
    calendarTo.add(Calendar.MONTH, months)
    calendarTo.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
    calendarTo.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0)
    calendarTo.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)
    calendarTo.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0)

    var weeks = -1
    while (calendarFrom.timeInMillis < calendarTo.timeInMillis) {
        calendarFrom.add(Calendar.DATE, 7)
        weeks++
        Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, "weeks $weeks")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy way

```
  Calendar cal1 = new GregorianCalendar();
    Calendar cal2 = new GregorianCalendar();
    cal1.set(2014, 3, 3);
    cal2.set(2015, 3, 6);

    weekscount.setText("weeks= "+ ( (cal2.getTime().getTime() - cal1.getTime().getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))/7);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to find the number of weeks between two dates.

```
SimpleDateFormat myFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy");
String classStartData = "31 01 2021";
String classEndData = "08 03 2021";

Date dateClassStart = myFormat.parse(classStartData);
Date dateClassEnd = myFormat.parse(classEndData);

long differenceWeek = dateClassEnd.getTime() - dateClassStart.getTime();
int programLength = (int)(TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(differenceWeek, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)/7);
System.out.println("Class length in weeks: " +programLength);
```

Answer (score 0):

After referring many solution, this worked for me.
{Provided I did not want to use external Libraries}

```
public static int getNumberOfWeeks(Date date1, Date date2) {
if (date1.after(date2)) {
        return getNumberOfWeeks(date2, date1);
    }

    Date date = date1;
    int days = 0;
    while (date.before(date2)) {
        days++;
        date = addDays(date, 1);
    }
    return days/7;
}
```

To add days to a date :

```
Date addDays(Date date, int days) {
    if (days == 0) {
        return date;
    } else {
        Date shiftedDate = new Date(date.getTime() + (long)days * 86400000L);
        return shiftedDate;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the following article: [Java - calculate the difference between two dates](http://tripoverit.blogspot.com/2007/07/java-calculate-difference-between-two.html)

The daysBetween method will allow you to get the number of days between dates. Then you can simply divide by 7 to get the number of full weeks.

Comment: That's wrong  - between Friday and Monday is 3 days, but one week.

Answer (score -1):

```
        Calendar date1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar date2 = Calendar.getInstance();

        date1.clear();
        date1.set(datePicker1.getYear(), datePicker1.getMonth(),
                datePicker1.getDayOfMonth());
        date2.clear();
        date2.set(datePicker2.getYear(), datePicker2.getMonth(),
                datePicker2.getDayOfMonth());

        long diff = date2.getTimeInMillis() - date1.getTimeInMillis();

        float dayCount = (float) diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

        int week = (dayCount / 7) ;
```

Hope this might Help you

Comment: This code assumes that every day has the same duration in milliseconds, which, due to daylight saving time and leap seconds, is not the case, and thus leads to wrong results.

Answer (score -1):

`public int diffInWeeks(Date start, Date end) {
    long diffSeconds = (end.getTime() - start.getTime())/1000;
    return (int)diffSeconds/(60 * 60 * 24 * 7);
}`

Comment: This will give incorrect results when the interval includes days which are not exactly 24 hours long, e.g. due to daylight savings time or leap seconds.