# Get Week from given Calendar Range?

Tags: android, android-calendar

I am implementing an application where I have two [calendar](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html) object with minimum and maximum date range.

1. Is there a way to get total week count
2. How can get week information based on index say: need 5th week of calendar range

any one have suggestion here ?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned here [Get the number of weeks between two Dates.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963147/get-the-number-of-weeks-between-two-dates) maybe you can use JodaTime http://www.joda.org/joda-time/

android version https://github.com/dlew/joda-time-android

```
 DateTime dateTime1 = new DateTime(date1);
 DateTime dateTime2 = new DateTime(date2);
 int weeks = Weeks.weeksBetween(dateTime1, dateTime2).getWeeks();
```