# I want to find the range of the week between a given date

Tags: java, android

[A user must enter a date, then I must display the range of the week between the given date, for this instance the range should be

Start date : Sun 10 Jan 2016, End date : Sat 16 Jan 2016 ][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bT02S.png)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    //get the day from the user

    //c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY); //I want to set the date here

    //The range of the given day   
    System.out.print("Start Date : " + c.getTime() + ", ");
    c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 6);
    System.out.println("End Date : " + c.getTime());
    c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1);

}
```

Comment: and what seems to be your trouble young man?

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963147/get-the-number-of-weeks-between-two-dates

Comment: What is your exact problem with the code you have put?

Comment: m heavenly struggling to get a date range, lets say a user gives a date, n I should find the date week range,                                                                                                                                            example the user select 13 Jan 2016, an the output should be                                                                          Start date : Sun Jan 2016, End date : Sat Jan 2016

Comment: Please try to elaborate your question.

Comment: Does you program produce the results you need? What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: public class TestDay
{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
   
   
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-M-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
  String dateInString = "13-01-2016 10:20:56";
  Date date = null;
  try{
   date = sdf.parse(dateInString);
  }catch(ParseException e)
  {
   
  }
  Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
  c.setTime(date); 
   
  c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SUNDAY);
       
  System.out.print("Start Date : " + c.getTime() + ", ");
  c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 6);
  System.out.println("End Date : " + c.getTime());
  c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1);
   
 }
}