# How can I find the number of weekends betwee 2 dates

Tags: java

My problem is the following I need to know how many week-ends are between 2 dates.
As I'm not satisfied with my solution I ask around.

```
int numberOfWeekendContained(LocalDate start, LocalDate end) {
    int weekends = 0;
    for (LocalDate day = startTime.toLocalDate(); !day.isAfter(end); day = day.plusDays(1)) {
        LocalDate previousDay = day.minusDays(1);
        if (isWeekEnd(day) && (!isWeekEnd(previousDay) || !isInRange(previousDay, start, end))) {
            weekends++;
        }
    }
    return weekends;
}

private static boolean isWeekEnd(LocalDate day) {
    return DayOfWeek.SATURDAY.equals(day.getDayOfWeek()) || DayOfWeek.SUNDAY.equals(day.getDayOfWeek());
}

private static boolean isInRange(LocalDate day, LocalDate start, LocalDate end) {
    return !day.isBefore(start) && !day.isAfter(end);
}
```

A Sunday or Saturday count as a full weekend. I.e., if my range goes from Sunday to Monday, I have 1 Weekend. If it goes from Sunday to next Saturday, it counts as 2.

I really don't like the if which is in my opinion is to complicated to be understood at first glance.

Has anyone an idea how to make this cleaner?

Comment: check if the start and the end are weekends, and then check for the number of weekends inbetween them (as well as if the two days are `>5` days apart, you can't have more than 1 weekend otherwise).

Comment: 1) Find the DOW of the first date. 2) Find the DOW of the second date. 3) Find the number of days in between. 3) We know a week has 7 days - apply maths.

Comment: Can you find the week of the year that a date falls on on? If so, I think you just find the absolute difference between the two. Obviously crossing over multiple years becomes difficult, though

Comment: @tobias_k Try actually reading the question, since it already says: *If it goes from Sunday to next Saturday, it counts as 2.*

Comment: If begin date is not a Monday, find the Monday before the begin date. If end date is not a Friday, find the Friday after the end date. Subtract those two dates, divide by 7 and take the int value.

Comment: your answer is here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963147/get-the-number-of-weeks-between-two-dates

Comment: @fan Rather than embed a solution within your Question, please post an Answer and accept it to mark the Question closed (resolved). Perfectly okay to post and accept your own Answer on Stack Overflow, according to official policy, encouraged actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tank you all for your comments. I go with Quintium's solution I think it is the clearer. i.e.,

```
int numberOfWeekendContained(LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate) {
    LocalDate start = startDate.with(TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame(DayOfWeek.MONDAY));
    LocalDate end = endDate.with(TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame(DayOfWeek.FRIDAY));
    return Period.between(start, end).getDays()/ DAYS_PER_WEEK;
}
```

DAY_PER_WEEK = 7 is a constant. Unfortunately I could not find the Joda Days.DAY_PER_WEEK equivalent in Java 8

Answer (score 2):

I think this does the trick :

```
public static int numberOfWeekendContained(LocalDate start, LocalDate end) {
    LocalDate firstMondayAfterStart = start.plusDays(8-start.getDayOfWeek().getValue());
    LocalDate lastSundayBeforeEnd = end.minusDays(end.getDayOfWeek().getValue());

    int numberOfWeeksInbetween = Math.floorDiv(Period.between(firstMondayAfterStart, lastSundayBeforeEnd).getDays() + 1, 7);

    return 
        Math.max(0, Math.min(2, 7 - start.getDayOfWeek().getValue())) +     // weekend days from the start week
        Math.max(0, end.getDayOfWeek().getValue() - 5) +                    // weekend days from the end week
        numberOfWeeksInbetween * 2;                                         // weekend days from the weeks inbetween

}
```

You can try it [here](https://ideone.com/aLWxd9).

Comment: I tried it between Fri 2016-12-02 and Tue 2016-12-06. It gave 2 as the answer. It should be 1.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou why should it be 1 ? I count 2016-12-03 and 2016-12-04 as weekend days between your two dates.

Comment: The question was how many *weekends* there are between two days, not how many weekend *days*.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou quoting OP "A Sunday or Saturday count as a full weekend". I know, weird way to phrase it.

Comment: Anyway if it wasn't what OP wants, the fix would be easy : change 7 to 6 in the first line of the return, 5 to 6 in the second line, and remove the *2 in the third line.