# How to get week interval in between two dates in android?

Tags: java, android, week-number, android-date

Hi I am writing a code which can show the week interval between current time and login time,

I am adding one function by which I am saving login time.

```
public void setWeek() {
    Date today = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String dateToStr = format.format(today);
    editor.putString("week", dateToStr).commit();
}

public String getWeek() {
    return pref.getString("week", null);
}
```

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: It’s not really clear to me, sorry. What is a week interval? So if login was 2 weeks ago, would the interval then be from 2019-W26 through 2019-W28? Or?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the number of weeks between two Dates.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963147/get-the-number-of-weeks-between-two-dates)

Comment: `ChronoUnit.WEEKS.between(LocalDate.parse(getWeek()), LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"))`. Will count only whole weeks; 1 week 6 days will be just 1 week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below method calculates no of week between two dates.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date startDate = dateFormat.parse("2019-01-01");
Date endDate = dateFormat.parse("2019-01-29");
int noOfWeek = calculateWeekNo(startDate, endDate);

   //Option 1
   public int calculateWeekNo(Date start, Date end) {
        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        cal.setTime(start);
        int weeks = 0;
        while (cal.getTime().before(end)) {
            cal.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 1);
            weeks++;
        }
       return weeks;
    }

   // Option 2
    public static int calculateWeekNo(Date start, Date end) {
         Calendar a = new GregorianCalendar();
         Calendar b = new GregorianCalendar();
         a.setTime(start);
         b.setTime(end);
         return b.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR) - a.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you out. I use this condition to get number of days back from inputs date and check if the days are 7 to run my conditions.

```
call conditionForWeek(){
    calendarToday = Calendar.getInstance();
        formatInstallDate = new SimpleDateFormat(FORMAT_DATE_DD_MMM_YY, Locale.ENGLISH);
        currentDate = formatInstallDate.format(calendarToday.getTime());
        installDate = PreferencesManager.getInstance().getString(USER_DATE_OF_INSTALL);

        int differenceInDate = PregnancyAppUtils.getDaysBetweenDates(currentDate, installDate);

        if (differenceInDate > 0 && differenceInDate % 7 == 0) {
                CallYourConditionHere();
        }
}


//This method will calculate difference in days and return the difference in days

    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
    public static int getDaysBetweenDates(String currentDate, String installDate) {
        formatConversion = new SimpleDateFormat(FORMAT_DATE_DD_MMM_YY);
        try {
            Date dateCurrent = formatConversion.parse(currentDate);
            Date dateAfterSevenDays;
            //take care of previous app version's date formats
            try {
                dateAfterSevenDays = formatConversion.parse(installDate);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                dateAfterSevenDays = getCalObjFromDefaultDate(installDate).getTime();
            }
            differenceInDate = dateCurrent.getTime() - dateAfterSevenDays.getTime();
            days = (int) (differenceInDate / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return days;
    }
```