# Number of days between two Instants doesn't change when changing a specific end date

Tags: java-17

I have a class that I use to get the number of days between 2 Instants :

```
public static Long getDaysBetween(final Instant startInstant, final Instant endInstant) {
    final ZonedDateTime startDate = startInstant.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    final ZonedDateTime endDate = endInstant.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    return ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(startDate, endDate);
}
```

And the corresponding test class

```
class WeekCalculatorTest {

    @Test
    void givenStartAndEndInstant_whenCalculatingTheNumberOfDaysBetween_thenTheResultShouldBe() {
        final String start = "2022-09-01T00:00:00Z";
        final String end = "2022-10-31T00:00:00Z";
        final Instant startInstant = Instant.parse(start);
        final Instant endInstant = Instant.parse(end);
        assertThat(WeekCalculator.getDaysBetween(startInstant, endInstant), is(59L));
    }
}
```

I don't understand why when I change the *end* variable to `final String end = "2022-10-30T00:00:00Z";`, my test is still passing.

Comment: Hmm, I see an unnecessary use of `ZonedDateTime` and `ZoneId.systemDefault()`, together with a sample date suspiciously close to the DST switch time. I guess, there’s no need to dig further (wouldn’t even be possible for me without knowing your result of `ZoneId.systemDefault()`). What’s the reason for this detour, instead of a simple `ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(startInstant, endInstant)`?

Comment: @Holger Indeed, I forgot to say that my ZoneId is `Europe/Paris`. The reason why I use `ZonedDateTime` in fact I need to use `ChronoUnit.WEEKS.between`. If I don't use the `ZonedDateTime` with the `ChronoUnit.WEEKS.between`, I get a `java.time.temporal.UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported unit: Weeks`.   
I got the awnser from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963147/get-the-number-of-weeks-between-two-dates)

Comment: I see. So the `T00:00:00Z` corresponds to 1:00 resp. 2:00 in your local time and `ZonedDateTime` will round down the number of days because there’s one incomplete day (23 hours) in this time span. So use either, `ZoneOffset.UTC`  instead of `ZoneId.systemDefault()`, as your input is given in UTC, or `ChronoUnit. … .between(LocalDate.ofInstant(startInstant, ZoneId.systemDefault()), LocalDate.ofInstant(endInstant, ZoneId.systemDefault()))` which ignores the differences on the hour scale.